# Conflict Probability Formula

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out what is the chance to obtain 2 identical strings if I'm randomly generating 64-bit strings continously. Is it possible to calculate the approximate interval of tries in which the conflict will occur ?

How would I obtain a basic formula for calculating this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be stated as the [Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) where the two 64 bit strings are the birthdays. That page will point you in the direction of how to set this up as a standard probability problem.  The restated problem would be, if people are added to a room at a rate of 1 / minute, what is the expected time till two people in the room have the same birthday.

You might be interested though in another sort of statistic. I imagine these are GUIDs and you want to be assured there is no conflict amongst them.  You might then want to find what is the maximal number of GUIDs so that the probability of conflict is less than some amount.

Comment: You got my exact point, I already knew about the Birthday problem, never checked far enough to see they actually have a table containing exactly what I need. Looking at their table, the probability is of 0.1, in 1.5x10^37 GUIDs. Translating that to 15e+36, the probability is neglectible. Thank you!